# How to get select data in json format in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT ss.name AS name, \n" +
            " SUM(pp.amount) AS amount, \n" +
            " REPLACE(ss.name, 'SomeName', 'DifferentName') AS cname \n" +
            " FROM payments AS pp\n" +
            " INNER JOIN auth_user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id\n" +
            " INNER JOIN services AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id\n" +
            " WHERE\n" +
            " pp.created_dt >= '2021-09-28' AND pp.created_dt < '2021-09-29' \n" +
            " AND ss.name = 'SomeName' AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS' \n" +
            " GROUP BY ss.name\n" //+
             , nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

My Entity

```
@Entity
//@Table(name = "payment")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    //@Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    //@Column(name = "amount")
    private long amount;

   // @Column(name = "name")
    private String cName;

    public User(
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("amount")long amount,
            @JsonProperty("cName")String cName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.cName = cName;
    }

    public User(long id, String name, long amount, String cName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.cName = cName;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public long getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getcName() {
        return cName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                ", cName='" + cName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthority() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        userDao.findAll();
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        return userDao.save(user);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> listUser() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User create(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.save(user);
    }
```

I'm a beginner and I want to write a simple rest service that will take data from my request to the repository and output it in json format to localhost: 8080. Nothing works for me. Help me please. How should I implement this.
I tried to do it myself, but I get a 404 error
I know that the repository method needs to be called in the controller. But most likely I'm doing something wrong ...
I have listed all the classes. In Postman, nothing is displayed for me

Comment: I am seeing only the Entity, and the JpaRepository.   What is it that you are after?  How to create a Service? How to create a Controller? What do you mean by JSON format to localhost:8080.   If you can clarify exactly in points what you need to achieve, someone could help.

Comment: @Susan Mustafa Everything is correct. I need a service and need a controller. How can I get my request data in JSON format? When starting the project, I would like to go to the browser and see on localhost the data that is received from my request specified in the repository in json format.

Comment: In Postman, do you have 200 but no data? or do you get 404.  Please put your postman request also.

You need to have some logging as well.  Do you see it actually reaching the Controller from your front-end?

Comment: @Susan Mustafa I get 404

Comment: paste your springboot log (on startup) so I can see port number.  Also take screenshot of your postman request.  You are doing something wrong on calling this...

Comment: {
    "timestamp": "2021-10-19T10:54:38.914+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/user"
}

Comment: ((http://localhost:port/users/user)) <-- is how you would call it..

Comment: @Susan Mustafa localhost:8080/users - ERROR 404 localhost:8080/users/user - ERROR 500

Comment: How do I add a screenshot here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add @Override above public List User findAll() method in UserServiceImpl class

Try,

```
http://localhost:8080/users/users
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/users/user
```

Both will give the same response.

Comment: did not help ERROR 500

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error from the postman and your application?

Comment: Have u added @Override above findAll() method in UserServiceImpl class?

Comment: I fixed everything. And put Override where you said. Fixed all bugs. The method now works. It turns out 200. But there is no data. A path array - []

Comment: Maybe now there is an error in the method itself? I mean, it returns (return list;). If this is the case, then I don’t understand why list is empty.

Comment: I ran debug. It showed that list: size = 0

Comment: change to public List<User> findAll() {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
       return userDao.findAll();
    }

Comment: You are returning empty list

Comment: Fabulous! Works) Thank you very much!